# Does OC4J Supports JAX-WS?

Tags: web-services, webserver, jax-ws, oc4j

I got the docs
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25221_05/web.1013/b14432/intro.htm#BABCDFAD
however i am not able to understand if OAS(OC4J) supports JAX-WS.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OC4J does not have *native* support for JAX-WS, this complies up to the J2EE 1.4 specification. JAX-WS (which would be something like JAX-RPC 2.0) is a feature of Java EE 5, already included in Java SE 6 and above.

However, it is possible to have this feature in OC4J. This [article](http://www.fransvanbuul.net/?p=8) provides some points to consider for the use of JAX-WS RI API.

See also:

- [Assembling Web Services with Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25221_05/web.1013/b14434/devannotation.htm) in OC4J
- [Working with JAX-WS Web Services: Brief History](http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/working-jax-ws-services-history/)
- [Web services hints and tips: JAX-RPC versus JAX-WS, Part 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc/index.html), from IBM developerWorks

Comment: alas the first link is dead now - the only comprehensive text I found about using JAX-WS in OC4J and Java 1.5 is in the Apache CXF documentation: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-OC4J